# IF- ELSE condition based on maximum column value in Python 3 (Jupyter Notebook)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, if-statement, jupyter-notebook

```
import pandas as pd

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=acc, 
                   columns=['Accuracy'], 
                   index=['DT','RF','KNN','NN','REG'])
df2 = df2.T
```

Goal: find which column has the maximum value and perform tasks accordingly

```
              DT           RF         KNN         NN         REG
Accuracy    98.882173   99.037636   78.016063   77.240633   54.059435
```

For example: in the above example, 'RF' has the maximum value. 
System info:

- Python 3
- Jupyter notebook.

**Pseudocode:**

```
max = Column name of maximum value    ('RF' in this case)

if (max=='RF'):
 ..xyx..
else if (max=='DT'):
 .. abcd...
etc...
```

Comment: depends on what sort of operations you want to do, look into `np.where` and `np.select`

Comment: @Datanovice why does it have to depend on the usage?

Comment: @dvlper depends how complex the operation is, if there is a single `if` then use `.loc` if `if/else` use `np.where` if multiple conditions use `np.select`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `idxmax` on orignal DataFrame without Transpose. For example:

```
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame(acc, columns = ['Accuracy'], index = ['DT','RF','KNN','NN','REG'])
>>> df2['Accuracy'].idxmax()
```

Output:

```
'RF'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find max column name by each row wise using [`DataFrame.idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html#pandas-dataframe-idxmax)

```py
>>> df
                 DT         RF        KNN         NN        REG
Accuracy  98.882173  99.037636  78.016063  77.240633  54.059435

>>> df.idxmax(axis=1)
Accuracy    RF
dtype: object
```

Comment: Yes, i got that. I'm not able to compare this value since its an object.

if (df.idmax(axis=1) ==' RF'):
      -perform xyz- 

This is what I'm stuck at

Comment: @MeghnaRoyChowdhury will be there always one row in dataframe? you can access it with `df.idxmax(axis=1)[0]`